# gpt2 detector gives RuntimeError: Default process group has not been initialized, please make sure to call init_process_group

Tags: pytorch, runtime

I'm trying to train openai detector in colab but I'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/train.py", line 316, in <module>
    run(**vars(args))
  File "/content/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/train.py", line 248, in run
    validation_metrics = validate(model, device, validation_loader)
  File "/content/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/train.py", line 144, in validate
    records = [record for v in range(votes) for record in tqdm(loader, desc=f'Preloading data ... {v}',
  File "/content/gpt-2-output-dataset/detector/train.py", line 145, in <listcomp>
    disable=dist.is_available() and dist.get_rank() > 0)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 1469, in get_rank
    default_pg = _get_default_group()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 940, in _get_default_group
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Default process group has not been initialized, please make sure to call init_process_group.
[2024-03-01 01:51:33,286] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api: [ERROR] failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 2032) of binary: /usr/bin/python3
```

Is this because I can't use DISTRIBUTEDDATAPARALLEL in colab? I am using colab pro. Or do I need to change the setup of distributed to be able to run it in colab? I tried to change it to DATAPARALLEL but I still see the same issue.

```
if world_size > 1:
        model = DistributedDataParallel(model, [rank], output_device=rank, find_unused_parameters=True)
```

Am I missing something?

The setup is done like this:

```
def setup_distributed(port=29500):
    if not dist.is_available() or not torch.cuda.is_available() or torch.cuda.device_count() <= 1:
        return 0, 1

    if 'MPIR_CVAR_CH3_INTERFACE_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
        from mpi4py import MPI
        mpi_rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
        mpi_size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()

        os.environ["MASTER_ADDR"] = '127.0.0.1'
        os.environ["MASTER_PORT"] = str(port)

        dist.init_process_group(backend="gloo", world_size=mpi_size, rank=mpi_rank)
        return mpi_rank, mpi_size

    dist.init_process_group(backend="gloo", init_method="env://")
    return dist.get_rank(), dist.get_world_size()
```

It's failing in this line

```
records = [record for v in range(votes) for record in tqdm(loader, desc=f'Preloading data ... {v}',
                                                               disable=dist.is_available() and dist.get_rank() > 0)]
```

Any guidance is appreciated.